# LESS file changes not working

Tags: static-content-deploy, less-css

the LESS file changes is not shown on frontend , i tired removing cache and different files
rm -rf  var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
then upgrading and deploying
but when i deploy the website is broken

Answer (score 0):

When making any change to the .less files within your custom theme, follow the following four steps.

1.Delete the files within: `<vendor>\var\view_preprocessed\pub\static\frontend`

2.Delete the files within: `<vendor>\var\cache`

3.Delete the files within: `<vendor>\pub\static\frontend\` using

4.If in production mode, run the setup:static-content:deploy command. If in developer mode, simply refresh the page you are attempting to style.

In summarized run the below commands

```
rm -rf pub/static
rm -rf var/cache
rm -rf var/page_cache
rm -rf var/view_processed
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Note: I assume that you have located your custom LESS file on the proper file path.